# In Vim, how do you get the number of lines in the current file using vimscript?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get the count of lines in the current file using vimscript but I can't figure out how (and google is returning a bunch of crap about showing line numbers).

Comment: I've never used vimscript, but this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/553257/778118

Comment: Don't use Google for that kind of thing. The answer is on your machine: `:help functions`.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use `line()` function:

```
:echo line('$')
```

Answer (score 54):

Pressing `ctrl-g` will reveal the filename, current line, the line count, your current position as a percentage, and your cursor's current column number.

Comment: Upon rereading the question, I realize you were trying to do this via vimscript. Sorry, my answer is not useful for that purpose.

Comment: Still, for someone who stumbled upon this from Google, this was the best answer for me

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
wc -l <filename>
```

Comment: Using that in a status line, for example, would spawn a process every update. The question clearly asks about an answer in vimscript.

Answer (score 2):

when you select an area, then vim shows in corner how many lines you have selected
if you have following in your .vimrc file:
`set statusline=%f\ %l,%c`

Comment: If the OP wants to use that number back into a vim script, neither `'statusline'` nor `CTRL-G`will be helpful to him. `line('$')` will return the number of lines in the current buffer, and `len(readfile(filename))` the number of lines in a given file.

Comment: title says nothing about script - perhaps it should be changed then

Comment: Indeed, the title says nothing about this. However, in the text, the OP has specified _"using vimscript"_. He may have expressed a mean(s?) that restricts, for no good reason, valid solutions to his real objective. In that case your answer and matty's answer would be perfectly valid. I cannot tell.

Comment: Changed the title :)

Answer (score 1):

In vi, i usually get the lines by the below method.

:set number and then
shift+g

Answer (score -1):

The variable `%L` already contains the total number of lines.

You could use `:echo %L` or `:set statusline+=%L` to append it to the status

Comment: your example ':echo %L' doesn't  work in gvim 7.4.580 on linux nor in 8.0.6 on windows.  The statusline example worked, but please include the version of vim one can use '%L' as a target of 'echo' on the vim-cmdline(':') for version/platform specific features.  Thanks!