# Vim - Count number of certain character

Tags: vim, count, match

I'm trying to define a function that does `A` if there's an even number of dollar signs (in my buffer), and `B` if there's an odd number of dollar signs. However, I'm unsure how to count the number of dollar signs, and then report that number for defining the function. For instance, entering

> :%s/\$//gn

will spit out this number on the status line. But how can one apply the result for defining a function?

Comment: There's a possible clue in this SO answer. [A: Fast word count function in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114431/fast-word-count-function-in-vim/4588161#4588161). There is a `v:statusmsg` that you can access that will contain the result of the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @DaveNewman's comment, you may write:

```
:%s/\$//gn | let i = split(v:statusmsg)[0] | if i % 2 | ... | else | ... | endif
```